# Creating slide menu in css

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an slide menu, the orange box goes to the corner of the menu, and white box with orange menu name appears.

The issue is when i use ***:hover***
and move mouse over that, it starts, and automatically goes at the start pos.

**How to make it finish it's animation?**

http://jsfiddle.net/JudgeDredd/XWmme/1/

```
    .smmo
    {
    width:195px;
    height:45px;
    background:#FF3300;
    position:relative;
    display:block;

    }


    .smmo:hover {

-webkit-animation-name:slideL ;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
 }
@-webkit-keyframes slideL /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {left:0px;}
to {left:200px;width:65px;}
}
```

Comment: Not much need to make a keyframe for this, you can just achieve this with a normal change of style son hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came with a solution using just `transition` and `:before` pseudo-element this way:

HTML

```
<div class="smmo">Your Title</div>
```

CSS

```
.smmo {
    position:relative;
    color:orange;
    text-align:center;
    width:195px;
    height:45px;
    line-height:45px;
}
.smmo:before
{
    content:" ";
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#FF3300;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    transition:all 1s;
}
.smmo:hover:before {
    left:200px;
    width:65px;
}
```

Check this **[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWmme/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add
`-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;`

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/xn5Uc/)

---

**Update**

> If you move your mouse anywhere on the object it will jerk back and forth over and over. –  Josh Powell

This can be fixed by adding a wrapper div for `.smmo` and animating `.smmo` on hover to it

```
.smmo-wrapper:hover .smmo {
    -webkit-animation-name:slideL;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/x67Cy/)

Comment: If you move your mouse anywhere on the object it will jerk back and forth over and over.